# How can you refresh the user attributes in a FME Desktop workspace?

Tags: fme-form

How can you refresh the user attributes in a workspace?

I have a FME workspace that is reading from a MapInfo table, and writing to SQL Server spatial table

The SQL table has had a new field added to it.

I want the new field to appear in the list of user attributes, but I can't see any "refresh" options. I can't believe it's a case of deleting the existing SQL writer and adding a new one

Answer (score 4):

You want Writers (or Readers) > Update Feature Type from the menubar - though re-importing the table and deleting the existing one will work just as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can either set 'Table Definition' to 'Automatic' when adding your writer...

[image]

...or set this behaviour under 'User Attributes' tab in the Feature Type Properties (double click writer).

[image]

Comment: Doesn't show the new field from the SQL table. I did get it to work by setting the table definition to "Import from Dataset" and then selecting the target table